# Get the column of the maximum element in a row and write it back in df

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose i have a DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'bar': [2, 1, 4, 10, 1, 1],
                           'baz': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]})

bar baz
0   2   1
1   1   2
2   4   3
3   10  1
4   1   2
5   1   3
```

I need to create a new column and write there the column name of the maximum element in the row:

```
    bar baz foo
la  2   1   bar
qw  2   1   bar
re  2   3   baz
gf  4   3   bar
hg  10  1   bar
ds  1   2   baz
ds  1   3   baz
```

At least, i got extracted this names like this:

```
a = hours.as_matrix()
for i in a:
    print(hours.columns[i.argmax()])
```

**But**, i cant wright it into the DataFrame, cause indexes are not integers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use [DataFrame.idxmax(axis=1)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html)

```
In [101]: df
Out[101]:
    bar  baz
la    2    1
qw    2    1
re    2    3
gf    4    3
hg   10    1
ds    1    2
ds    1    3

In [102]: df['foo'] = df.idxmax(1)

In [103]: df
Out[103]:
    bar  baz  foo
la    2    1  bar
qw    2    1  bar
re    2    3  baz
gf    4    3  bar
hg   10    1  bar
ds    1    2  baz
ds    1    3  baz
```